# how to use SGBM algorithm in stereo_image_proc

Tags: slam, navigation, stereo-camera, rtabmap-ros, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

stereo_image_proc by default uses **StereoBM** algorithm how can we change this to **SGBM**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225053/how-to-use-sgbm-algorithm-in-stereo_image_proc/) by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2016-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found it the algorithm is set to StereoBM by default  in the

> image_pipeline/stereo_image_proc/cfg/Disparity.cfg

file at line 14 : gen.add("stereo_algorithm", int_t, 0, "sterel algorithm", `0`, 0, 1,
edit_method = stereo_algo_enum)

change the second last `0` in the line to 1 it will do...    :)

---

Originally posted by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) with karma: 90 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0